# Con't Catch MySQL Resource Limit Exceeded error in PDO Connection(Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager) in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

After applying max_updates_per_hour = 5 on mysql user. When try to insert or update or delete records using mysqli connection, after succssfuly complete 5 opertaions, its throwing error like "1226: User 'Ex' has exceeded the 'max_updates_per_hour' resource (current value: 5)",

But when tried with PDO Connecton, its not throwing error. I need to catch PDO Exception for this.

I tried below examples:

```
$results = $smt->execute(array('PHP','test'));
if(!$results ){
     echo "Something went wrong!"; exit;
}
```

and

```
try{
    $results = $smt->execute(array('PHP','test'));
} 
catch(Exception $e){
    echo 'Something went wrong! ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Did you enabled PDO exception handling? This you can do via the options parameter when you create the connection (https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php). After enabling the exception handler your try catch block should work.

Comment: Yes I enabled PDO Exception, but its not throwing  1226 User 'test' has exceeded the 'max_updates_per_hour' resource errors

Comment: I made a test byself and you're right, there is no exception thrown in this case. This seems to be a bug in the PHP PDO extension itself.

There you can report this bug: https://bugs.php.net/